# Unable to build project with upgrade to android gradle 3.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-3.0

I am trying to update android `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7` to `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`. I am using Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 from canary branch. It looks like I did things [by the book](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) , but I am unable to compile my project with the new setup. I have provided a brief description of of my gradle file below and the error log as an output of assembling the build.

Here's the buildscript part of my gradle file.

***Gradle buildscript***

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'

        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

        classpath 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.6'
    }
}
```

***Gradle android***

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25

        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }

    // API 23 removes the http apache libraries, we require this to continue using them. We should
    // eventually move away from them and then remove this
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        // product flavors here
    }
}
```

***Error***

```
Issues:
 - WARN: {PROJECT-PATH}/core/res/layout/preference_layout.xml:20 generated id android:id/summary for external package android
 - WARN: {PROJECT-PATH}/core/res/layout/preference_category_layout.xml:15 generated id android:id/title for external package android
 - ERROR: {PROJECT-PATH}/androidSDK/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeAospDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6213 style attribute @android:attr/windowEnterAnimation not found
 - ERROR: {PROJECT-PATH}/androidSDK/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeAospDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6214 style attribute @android:attr/windowExitAnimation not found
 - ERROR: {PROJECT-PATH}/androidSDK/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeAospDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6226 style attribute @android:attr/windowEnterAnimation not found
 - ERROR: {PROJECT-PATH}/androidSDK/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeAospDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6227 style attribute @android:attr/windowExitAnimation not found
 - ERROR:  failed linking references
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.AaptV2Jni.buildException(AaptV2Jni.java:154)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.AaptV2Jni.makeValidatedPackage(AaptV2Jni.java:98)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractAapt.link(AbstractAapt.java:40)
        ... 49 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error. I actually had to remove the `"@"` character from the attribute name:

***Before:***

```
<style name="slideUpAnimation">
    <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_bottom</item>
    <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_bottom</item>
</style>
```

***After***

```
<style name="slideUpAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_bottom</item>
</style>
```